# Java FilterImplementation for session checking

Tags: java

I creating a web application using JSF,Hibernate,Spring. I have added a filter for checking session. My Filter code is :

```
public class AdminFilter implements Filter{

     private ArrayList<String> urlList;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
       String urls = filterConfig.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
       StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");   
       urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            urlList.add(token.nextToken());  
        }
    }

    // Checking if user is logged in
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                HttpServletRequest req= (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp= (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String url = req.getServletPath();
        HttpSession session =   req.getSession();
                if(!urlList.contains(url) && session.getAttribute("user")==null) 
                {
                    resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/backend/login/index.xhtml");

                }
          chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

In the init method of filter i have some avoid URL for which session checking should be skipped, like for login page itself. This is working correct but this filter is restricting my CSS,images and JS to load on the login page. 
Suggest me what is the problem in my filter ?

Comment: What have you added in `urlList` to skip js, css ?, It should be something like `/PATH/TO/CSS/FROM/WEBROOT/CSS/`

Comment: <init-param>
            <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
            <param-value>/backend/login/index.xhtml</param-value>
 </init-param>

Comment: Do you have any param for CSS, JS, Images ?(those are being used on login page) ?

Comment: no i haven't added avoid URL for css,images, and JS. But i think it is not good practice to add those urls in web.xml. There must be a better way

Comment: I don't think so, if you don't want to put it in web.xml, you could put it in separate xml file and just mention that file in web.xml and parse and create the list from init but that is longer way

Comment: can you use declarative security ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login page needs some resources (CSS, JS, Images) which are requested from browser in separate request which will be intercepted by Filter and since you don't have any parameters that skips such requests for resources (being used on login page) it will block this request

**Suggestion:**

You could use [Spring-Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/), rather than investing time in writing yours, it has got lots of flexibility by configuration

Comment: Ok, i got this. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your current config, Currently your filter is ignoring if the URL is for fetching css, images or any other resource.

```
boolean staticResources = (url.contains("css") || url.contains("images"));
if(!urlList.contains(url) && session.getAttribute("user")==null && !staticResources)  {
      resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/backend/login/index.xhtml");
}
```

This will avoid session checking for static contents.

Better way of doing this will be using the declarative security as part of [Java EE Web Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) using realm.