# J2EE filter : login page unable to load the css or any images

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I have already visited [Java FilterImplementation for session checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973997/java-filterimplementation-for-session-checking/10974023#10974023) link, which says about Spring security. I did not get the help i need.

After applying filter login.jsp is unable to load CSS and images.

I am trying simple example providing filter in web.xml and applying the filter on pages other than login.jsp.
Web.xml file is :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
 <filter>
 <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter2</filter-name>
 <filter-class>filter.AuthorizationFilter2</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
    <param-value>login.jsp</param-value>
 </init-param>`
 <filter>
```

And the filter class is :

```
    private ArrayList<String> urlList;

public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("authorization filter2 destroy method....");
}




public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    System.out.println("authorization filter2 doFilter method....");

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    String url = request.getServletPath();

    System.out.println("ppp:"+request.getRequestURL());

    System.out.println("url is :"+url);

    boolean allowedRequest = false;

    System.out.println("url list is :"+urlList);

    if(urlList.contains(url.substring(1))) {
        allowedRequest = true;
    }
    System.out.println("request allowed....."+allowedRequest);     
    if (!allowedRequest) {

        Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

        /*HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);*/
       /* if (null == session) {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }*/

        System.out.println("session contains login :"+session.containsKey("login"));



        if(!session.containsKey("login")){
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }

    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("authorization filter2 init method....");
    String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");

    urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
        urlList.add(token.nextToken());

    }
}
```

Login page contains `css` and `images` as per the requirement.

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


    String uri = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI();

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

    if ( uri.indexOf("/css") > 0){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if( uri.indexOf("/images") > 0){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if( uri.indexOf("/js") > 0){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if (session.containsKey("login")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else {
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath() + "/login?authentication=failed");
    }
}
```

put this block of code in your action class , it works.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS files and images used on logjn.jsp page have to be excluded from your filter

Comment: url = request.getServletPath();
the above statement in the filter class gives weird results like : /images/login.jsp
/images/test.png
/css/login.jsp

Though the url is login.jsp

Comment: This is because your response.sendRedirect("login.jsp") contains relative path. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String). So when the browser tries to get some CSS file (ex. /css/someFile.css), the filter redirects it to /css/login.jsp. Use FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools to see all the requests from the browser - it will help you to understand what is going on.

Comment: you are right, when i hit the login.jsp url it internally hits many other url like css/login.jsp , images/login.jsp
but i am not able to find the solution for it can you please help me in that. Thanks

Comment: You should either exclude css and images directory in your filter or change the filter mapping in web.xml file, so that your filter will not be applied to those locations.

Comment: r u talking about something like this,
<filter>
 <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter2</filter-name>
 <filter-class>filter.AuthorizationFilter2</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
    <param-value>login.jsp, *.css, *.js, *.png</param-value>
 </init-param>`
 <filter>